# How to Set Specific Date and time in Field of SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, calculated-column-formula

I have a requirement where we need to create a view in a sharepoint to filter items created after 4pm on Friday until next week 4pm on friday.

This is what i have accoimplished so far.

Created a Custom Column (StartDate) of type date and time with a default value of Today's Date. This Gives me Current Date and Time.

Then i created a Calculated Column named (Friday) with following  Formula:

```
=StartDate-WEEKDAY(StartDate)+6
```

Of return type Date and Time. Which Gave me  Friday of that week.

Now how do i set time on the field, so it would be 4:00pm Friday.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

by default it would give you 12:00 because you are using [today] add 16 hrs and it would become 4 pm
[detail on how to add hours](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2008/08/19/sharepoint-today-plus-1-hour-formula.aspx)

Comment: In StartDate i am using [Created] Field  So i am getting Created Date and Time which is not 12:00.